# Table creation along with dynamic partitioning (interval partitioning) in Oracle 10g EE

Tags: partitioning, oracle-10g

I am trying to create partitioning using interval partitioning using the below given query:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA_HOURLY
(
  tmstamp TIMESTAMP,
  elementName VARCHAR2(255), 
) PARTITION BY RANGE (tmstamp) 
interval (numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH'))
(
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('2016-01-31','yyyy-mm-dd'))
);
```

The error that I am getting in SQL Developer is:

> SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>   00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that interval partitioning was introduced on [Oracle 11g.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1#interval_partitioning)

Comment: Oracle 10g was released in 2003, you really need to upgrade

Comment: Ran this query on Oracle 11g EE...working fine.